# DataTables server side: query with GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: php, datatables, server-side

I am using DataTables server side to display my data.
([example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html))
 ([manual](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side)).

I was able to extend this tool with group by:

```
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $groupby )
);
```

and in the class ssp.class.php

```
$data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
    "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
     FROM `$table`
     $where
     $groupby
     $order
     $limit"
);
```

but when I want a SUM of a column, I got an error that the column SUM(GrossPrice) was not found.

Here is how the columns are processed:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'ProductDescription',  'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'SUM(GrossPrice)',   'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'SUM(Number)',   'dt' => 2 )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question but i answer for who have same problem.

You can use [this class](https://github.com/emran/ssp) with joinQuery. We use joinQuery because if we don't use, SSP class will use own queries.

```
$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'x.ProductDescription', 'dt' => 0, 'field' => 'ProductDescription'),
    array('db' => 'SUM(x.GrossPrice) as GrossPrice', 'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'GrossPrice'),
    array('db' => 'SUM(x.Number) as Number', 'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'Number')
);
```

joinQuery example:

```
$joinQuery = "FROM {$table} AS x";
```

And call like this:

```
echo json_encode(
   SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $joinQuery)
);
```

This class customized for JOIN query but you can use like this. Thanks to [Emran](https://github.com/emran) for this class.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround solution:

I created a view in mysql with the 'sum()'-query and just used datatables to display this view.

Hope this serves other people.